# Sequence startup of list of services in RHEL 7 where service startup order needs to be maintained

Tags: rhel7

I have a list of services which needs to be started but they are startups is interdependent. Meaning, only after first service is up, second service startup should occur. In short, order needs to be maintained.

Is there a way in RHEL 7 to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use systemd units and their `Wants` and `After` directives. See [Configure ordering of systemd services](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206093/configure-ordering-of-systemd-services) at Unix & Linux for details.

See also [Creating and Modifying Systemd Unit Files](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files.html) for an explanation of the syntax and other general information.